# Por que meu hooks personalizado retorna undefined ReactJS NextJS?

Tags: javascript, react, layout-responsivo, react-hooks, next.js

### Foi criado um viewportContext que envolve todo o App, assim posso capturar o tamanho da tela.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const viewportContext = createContext({});

function Viewport({ children }) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  // console.log(width, height);

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <viewportContext.Provider value={{ width, height }}>
      {children}
    </viewportContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Viewport;
```

### Esse é o hooks personalizado

##### No hooks useViewport, o mesmo não está passando os dimensionamentos da tela para o MyComponent. Com isso não consigo reenderizar o componente desejado de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
const viewportContext = createContext({});

export const useViewport = () => {
  const { width, height } = useContext(viewportContext);
  return { width, height };
};
```

### Esse é o componente que deve renderizar apenas o componente correspondente ao width informado

```
import React from "react";
import { useViewport } from "../../hooks/Viewport/useViewport";

const MobileComponent = () => <p>"Screen mobile"</p>;
const DesktopComponent = () => <p>"Screen desktop"</p>;

function MyComponent() {
  const { width } = useViewport();
  const breakpoint = 765;

  console.log(width);

  return width < breakpoint ? <MobileComponent /> : <DesktopComponent />;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Indique qual é o erro, a respectiva mensagem e onde ele ocorre.

Comment: No hooks useViewport, o mesmo não está passando os dimensionamentos da tela para o MyComponent. Com isso não consigo reenderizar o componente desejado de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais provavel de ter acontecido é que voce deve ter esquecido de renderizar o MyComponent dentro do componente que contém o contexto.

**O componente só vai poder usar o hook se estiver dentro do contexto**, já que vc utiliza o usecontext.

***Fiz um teste no [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-heyrovsky-s0l8l5?file=/src/index.js) e funcionou corretamente***

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import { Viewport, MyComponent } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Viewport>
      <MyComponent />
    </Viewport>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";

const viewportContext = createContext({});

export const useViewport = () => {
  const { width, height } = useContext(viewportContext);
  return { width, height };
};

const MobileComponent = () => <p>"Screen mobile"</p>;
const DesktopComponent = () => <p>"Screen desktop"</p>;

//COMPONENTE DENTRO DO PROVIDER
export function MyComponent() {
  const { width } = useViewport();
  console.log(width);
  const breakpoint = 765;

  console.log(width);

  return width < breakpoint ? <MobileComponent /> : <DesktopComponent />;
}
//COMPONENTE DENTRO DO PROVIDER

export function Viewport({ children }) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  // console.log(width, height);

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <viewportContext.Provider value={{ width, height }}>
      {children}
    </viewportContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Erra isso mesmo, falta de atenção. Obrigado meu nobre o app ficou top

Comment: boa tmj jovem!!